# How do I force gdm 3.6 stay on DISPLAY :0?

Tags: gentoo, gnome3, gdm

Every time I log out of my session, gdm moves to a different DISPLAY variable. Judging from /var/log/gdm, it rotates between :0 and :5.

I'm finding no documentation on this logic. How do I keep gdm on :0?

Comment: This behavior is different on gdm-3.16. Now a `gdm` instance always active on `vt1`.